# how to address directories and files by their rank

Tags: bash, directory

I have a directory containing 6 directory:

animal

```
   cat
   cow
   dog 
       a
       b
   donkey
   monkey
   zebra
```

I wanted to address them in a bash file by their rank(when the directories are sorted by alphabet, each one has a rank)

So for example I want to copy third directory which is dog.
I don't want to mention the name dog, I want to refer to it as third-directory in animal folder.
so for example cp -r home/animal/"third directory" ..

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GNU find and GNU sort to create an array.

In bash before 4.4 using a while read loop

```
while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    Animal+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z)

cp -r "/home/animal/${Animal[3]}" "target"
```

or if you have bash 4.4 you can skip the loop and use readarray

```
IFS= readarray -d '' Animal < <(find . -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z)

cp -r "/home/animal/${Animal[3]}" "target"
```

Comment: However, it is not clear if the op expects the sorting to be byte-wise. Why not `LC_ALL=en_US` for instance.

Comment: @sjsam It wasn't specified how it should be sorted so just chose `C` as it is the simplest,safest locale. OP can change easily dependant on how they wish to sort.

Comment: It works, thanks!
for my project I need to open one directory(for example a/b/) using this method and then in that directory(b), open an other directory using this method(a/b/c/), but when I repeat this script, it miss behave, any idea?

while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    a+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z)
cd `pwd`/${a[2]} 

while IFS= read -d '' file; do
    b+=( "$file" )
done < <(find . -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z)
cd `pwd`/${b[1]}

Comment: @mohammadreza Update your question with the new requirements.

Comment: @123 I found the problem, when there is sub directories in my directories, the script we also take into account the sub directories when it try to rank the directories.
for example, for above directories, your script recognized cat as directory 1,cow is recognized as directory 2, dog is recognized as directory 3 and a is recognized as directory 4 which makes the problem.
I don't want the script take into account the sub directories when ranking the folders,
Any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to fill an array with directory names:

```
cd /home/animal
animal=(foobar *)
cd -
cp -r "/home/animal/${animal[3]}" "target"
```

Comment: May be worth mentioning the `foobar` serves as an offset to start the actual count from one :) Nice one anyways.